# program for all possible arrangements of nxn matrix giving unique sum in c

Tags: c, magic-square

I want a logic for how to get unique sum like in `3x3` matrix the number from 1 to 9 (should not be repeated) the matrix looks like

```
     4 9 2
     3 5 7
     8 1 6
```

here the sum is 15.

if i input 3x3 matrix it should return this matrix

please help.

Comment: You want to make magic squares, but what do you mean by "if I input 3x3 matrix"? You mean if you input those dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking of the Magic Square problem, I would guess:

http://pages.prodigy.net/tetrasulfide/magicsquares.html